# Rails form_for edit not saving changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-routes

I'm new to rails and having trouble getting my edit form to update attributes.

Here is my routes.rb for project and note:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :notes
end
```

And this is my form_for in views/notes/edit.html.erb:

```
      <%= form_for [@project, @note] do |f| %>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :title %>
          <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :body %>
          <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 10, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="action">
          <%= f.submit "Save Note", class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

And finally this is my notes_controller.rb:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @notes = Note.all
    end

    def new
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @note = @project.notes.new
    end

    def create
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @note = @project.notes.build(note_params)
      @note.project = @project
      @note.save ? flash[:notice] = "Note created." : flash[:error] = "Note could not be created, please try again."
      redirect_to [current_user, @project]
    end

    def show
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
      if @note.update_attributes(note_params)
        @note.save
        flash[:notice] = "Note updated."
        redirect_to authenticated_root_path
      else
        flash[:error] = "Could not update note."
        render :edit
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @note.delete ? flash[:notice] = "Note deleted." : flash[:error] = "Note could not be deleted."
      redirect_to user_project_path
    end

    private

    def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:title, :body)
    end

    def find_note
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @note = @project.notes.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

This is what my terminal is outputting:

```
Started GET "/projects/12/notes/13/edit?utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=patch&authenticity_token=vnIoOSi0ksMNI7uU0aMnBpkTBWi75wy%2BYvbs3RxO5sPIbvFzDA30%2B32dJxurdcsiu9zsIpuDCR%2FARUamBRrYmg%3D%3D&note%5Btitle%5D=Transporter+Materials&note%5Bbody%5D=Star+dust%2C+data&commit=Save+Note" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-25 08:38:16 -0700
Processing by NotesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vnIoOSi0ksMNI7uU0aMnBpkTBWi75wy+Yvbs3RxO5sPIbvFzDA30+32dJxurdcsiu9zsIpuDCR/ARUamBRrYmg==", "note"=>{"title"=>"Transporter Materials", "body"=>"Star dust, data"}, "commit"=>"Save Note", "project_id"=>"12", "id"=>"13"}
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  Note Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "notes".* FROM "notes" WHERE "notes"."project_id" = ? AND "notes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 12], ["id", 13]]
  Rendered notes/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 328ms (Views: 296.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@project.notes.build(note_params)`.
No need of this `@note.project = @project` in create action

and in update

if you are using `@note.update_attributes(note_params)`
this is not required `@note.save`
and its better try to debug it using `@note.update_attributes!(note_params)`

it will give you why its not able to save.

`<%= form_for [@project, @note], :url => project_note_path(@project,@note), :method => :put do |f| %>`

Comment: While this does provide improvements, it does not provide the cause of the issue. A `GET` request is being issued.

Comment: @D-side get request has been issued you are right, but for edit action not for update.

Comment: Yep, to the exact same page this form is on.